# RequireJS loading a file that needs current file as dependency

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs

I am currently building a base for AngularJS in combination with RequireJS and so far I got everything working. there's just a little thing that I do not understand at this point. I have a file which creates the angular module, when this module is created it requires a controller and assigns it to the module. The strange thing though, the controller needs the module as dependency while in the module's file the module has not been returned yet because the require statement is executed before the return statement. This somehow seems to work but it has a bad smell to it.

**Module file:**

```
// Home is defined here and can later be used in controllers (and Services)
define('home', ['require', 'angular'], function(require, angular) {
    var homeModule = angular.module('AngularBase.home', ['AngularBase.core']);

    homeModule.config(['$controllerProvider', '$provide', '$compileProvider', function($controllerProvider, $provide, $compileProvider) {
        // We need this in order to support lazy loading
        homeModule.controller = $controllerProvider.register;
        homeModule.factory = $provide.factory;
        // And more, not relevant at this moment
    }]);

    // It loads the controller that depends on this module here
    require(['modules/home/controllers/homeController'], function() {
        // Dependencies loaded
    });

    // Yet in my mind controllers that need this module can only use it when the following return statement is called.
    return homeModule;
});
```

**Controller File:**

```
// As you can see this controller depends on home while home hasn't returned its module yet
// Yet it seems to work just fine
define(['home'], function(home) {
    home.controller('homeController', ['$scope', 'homeService', function($scope, homeService) {
        $scope.title = 'Home controller';
    }]);
});
```

I assume that it is not a good approach to do it like this and therefore I need some suggestions on how to make this happen in a clean way. I thought about grabbing the AngularBase.home module via `angular.module('AngularBase.home')` in the controller file and defining my controller on this. This however no longer allows me to insert a mockModule for testing in this controller via RequireJS's map function.

```
map: {
    '*' : {
        'home' : 'mock-module'
    }
}
```

Any suggestions on how to refactor this into a more clean solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution to my problem. In the end it seems to be just fine to do it the way I am currently doing it. When a file is called and has a define statement in it it will wait until all dependencies are available until the function is executed. This means that the controller will actually wait for the module to finish initializing before calling its function to register itself.

The way I am doing it above is just fine.

Source: http://www.slideshare.net/iivanoo/handlebars-and-requirejs (slides 11 till 24)